# How do I solve for $\delta$ in this question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-sum

$316.45 = 100e^{\delta(10)} + 100e^{\delta(5)}$

I don't know why I can't do this. I thought of using $\ln$ but I don't think $\ln(A+B) = \ln(A) + \ln(B)$ or does it?

Comment: Is $\delta$ a constant or a function?

Comment: A constant in this case. It's equal to 0.0597

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Let $x = e^{5\delta}$. Notice that $e^{10\delta} = (e^{5\delta})^2$. Then we have

$$316.45 = 100x^2 + 100x$$

Solve as usual for $x$, and retrieve $\delta$ afterwards.

Comment: Now I feel really stupid. Thanks for pointing that out ^^')

Comment: These questions can look tricky but a simple substitution often does the job. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

we have $\ln(ab)=\ln(a)+\ln(b)$ and your equation is simplified $3.1645=e^{\delta(10)}+e^{\delta(5)}$

Comment: i thought $\delta(10)$ and $\delta(5)$ are functions